# Multithreading in java having array of threads

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public static void getTestData() {

        try {

            filename = "InventoryData_" + form_id;

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("/Users/pnroy/Documents/" +filename + ".txt");
            pids = new ArrayList<ProductId>();
            GetData productList = new GetData();
            System.out.println("Getting productId");
            pids = productList.GetProductIds(form_id);
            int perThreadSize = pids.size() / numberOfCrawlers;
            ArrayList<ArrayList<ProductId>> perThreadData = new    
            ArrayList<ArrayList<ProductId>>(numberOfCrawlers);
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfCrawlers; i++) {
                perThreadData.add(new ArrayList<ProductId>(perThreadSize));
                for (int j = 0; j < perThreadSize; j++) {
                    ProductId ids = new ProductId();
                    ids.setEbProductID((pids.get(((i - 1) * perThreadSize + j))).getEbProductID());
                    ids.setECProductID((pids.get(((i - 1) * perThreadSize + j))).getECProductID());
                    perThreadData.get(i - 1).add(ids);
                }
            }

            BlockingQueue<String> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
            Consumer c1 = new Consumer(q);
            Thread[] thread = new Thread[numberOfCrawlers];
            for (int k = 0; k <= numberOfCrawlers; k++) {
                // System.out.println(k);
                GetCombinedData data = new GetCombinedData();
                thread[k] = new Thread(data);
                thread[k].setDaemon(true);
                data.setVal(perThreadData.get(k), filename, q);
                thread[k].start();

                // writer.println(data.getResult());
            }
            new Thread(c1).start();
            for (int l = 0; l <= numberOfCrawlers; l++) {
                thread[l].join();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } 
    }
```

Here number of crawlers is the number of threads.

The run method of GetCombined class has the following code:
The pids is passed as perThreadData.get(k-1) from the main method
The class CassController queries a API and i get a string result after some processing.

```
 public void run(){
        try{

        for(int i=0;i<pids.size();i++){
            //System.out.println("before cassini");
        CassController cass = new CassController();
        String result=cass.getPaginationDetails(pids.get(i));
        queue.put(result);
       // System.out.println(result);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
         writer.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
```

Consumer.java has the following code :

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable{
    private final BlockingQueue queue;
     Consumer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
    public void run(){
        try {
               while (queue.size()>0) 
               { 
                   consume(queue.take());
               }
             } catch (InterruptedException ex)
               { 
               }

    }
    void consume(Object x) { 
        try{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("/Users/pnroy/Documents/Inventory", true));
        writer.println(x.toString());
        writer.close();
        }catch(IOException ex){

        }

    }
```

So if i set the number of crawlers to 10 and if there are 500 records each thread will process 50 records.I need to write the results into a file.I am confused how i can achieve this since its a array of thread and each thread is doing a bunch of operations.

I tried using blocking queue but that is printing repetitive results.I am new to multi threading and not sure how can i handle the case.
Can you please suggest.

Comment: Do you have to use an array of threads for this? If you don't, use an `ExecutorService` instead, you'll find life so much easier.

Comment: Why would your program call `setDaemon(true)` on a thread that it is later going to `join()`?

Comment: It probably would help other programmers to understand your code if you would use noun-like names for your classes and variables, and verb-like names for your methods.  Methods _do_ things, objects _are_ things.

Comment: Your example contains references to classes, methods, types, and variables that you haven't shown to us.  You will greatly improve your chances of getting a useful answer if you can turn your question into an SSCCE.  http://sscce.org/

Comment: Also, your code is unnecessarily obfuscated. Iterate from 0 instead of 1, and thus use `thread[k]` instead of `thread[k - 1]`. Use `new GetCombinedData()` instead of `GetCombinedData.class.newInstance()`. Indent your code. It screams to the world: "I'm a newbie". Threads are a very, very complex topic. I have the feeling you still need to learn the basics before dealing with threads.

Comment: Added as much code as possible if this explains better

Answer (score -1):

With the introduction of many useful high-level concurrency classes, it now recommended not to directly use the `Thread` class anymore. Even the `BlockingQueue` class is rather low-level.

Instead, you have a nice application for the `CompletionService`, which builds upon the `ExecutorService`. The below example shows how to use it.

You want to replace the code in `PartialResultTask` (that's where the main processing happens) and `System.out.println` (that's where you probably want to write your result to a file).

```
public class ParallelProcessing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executionService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        CompletionService<String> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executionService);

        // submit tasks
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            completionService.submit(new PartialResultTask(i));
        }

        // collect result
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            String result = getNextResult(completionService);
            if (result != null)
                System.out.println(result);
        }

        executionService.shutdown();
    }

    private static String getNextResult(CompletionService<String> completionService) {

        Future<String> result = null;
        while (result == null) {
            try {
                result = completionService.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignore and retry
            }
        }

        try {
            return result.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }


    static class PartialResultTask implements Callable<String> {

        private int n;

        public PartialResultTask(int n) {
            this.n = n;
        }

        @Override
        public String call() {
            return String.format("Partial result %d", n);
        }
    }
}
```